# How to build charts in Jenkins from vmstat log file?

Tags: linux, performance, jenkins, charts, continuous-integration

If I have Linux performance statistic collected in *.txt file using vmstat command, is it possible to build charts for Linux performance metrics in Jenkins based on this vmstat log?

Comment: Doesn't Jenkins [Plot Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) fit your needs?

Comment: @taringamberini, this plugin makes chart from build to build, but I need another thing - to vizualize each performance metric collected in vmstat command during each test over time during the test. Is it possible realize in Jenkins?